# Selecting a range of words after the find text word and stop before another second word. ( Range after and stop before )

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've been going through the forums, but I'm unable to best match to get i wanna do.

I wanna copy a after searching for a keyword, e.g. Find ( Apple ) then select copy everything of it for the next few paragraphs and stop the range before the next word ( AppleEnd)

I tried this initially,

```
  Dim rng1 As Word.Range
  Dim rng2 As Word.Range
  Dim findthetext As String

If part12 = 1 Then

Set rng1 = ActiveDocument.Range
If rng1.Find.Execute(FindText:="SLHT") Then

Set rng2 = ActiveDocument.Range(rng1.End, ActiveDocument.Range.End)

If rng2 = Find.Execute(FindText:="SLHTEND") Then

findthetext = ActiveDocument.Range(rng1.End, rng2.Start).Text

 Selection.Copy

 Windows("Doc2").Activate

 Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)
```

However i get an Object error code

Hence i tried this method

```
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim rng3 As Range
Dim copyrange1 As Range
Dim copyrange2 As Range
Dim copyrange3 As Range



Dim findthetext As String


Set rng1 = ActiveDocument.Range
Set rng2 = ActiveDocument.Range
Set rng3 = ActiveDocument.Range



With rng1.Find
.Text = "SLCB"

 While .Execute
If Found = True Then
Set copyrange1 = rng1
copyrange1.Select

rng2.Start = copyrange1.End
rng2.End = ActiveDocument.Content.End

rng2.Select


 With rng2.Find
 .Text = "SLCBEND"

 If .Found = True Then
 Set copyrange3 = rng2
 copyrange3.Select

 End If
 End With


 rng3.Start = copyrange.Start
 rng3.End = copyrange3.End
 rng3.Select
 rng3.Copy

Windows("Doc2").Activate
Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)

 End If


End Sub
```

The second one im getting error about While error, how to i put a stop to it? or how can i replace it?

Which is better between the two

Appreciate the guidance.

Answer (score 0):

To Find all of:

( Apple ) then select copy everything of it for the next few paragraphs and stop the range before the next word ( AppleEnd)

simply use a *wildcard* Find, where:

Find = (( Apple)*\1End)

Similarly, for your 'SLHT ... SLHTEND' range, use:

Find = (SLHT)*\1END

In code, that might look like:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "(SLHT)*\1END"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute
  End With
  If .Find.Found = True Then
    MsgBox .Text
  End If
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Note that wildcard Finds are case-sensitive.